# wkhtmltopdf export svg file to pdf "tight" - without margins?

Tags: pdf, svg, wkhtmltopdf

I use on Windows 10, under MSYS2:

```
$ wkhtmltopdf.exe --version
wkhtmltopdf 0.13
```

( I have also tried wkhtmltopdf 0.12.6 (with patched qt) - but it cannot convert the texts in the SVG correctly )

I want to convert the following SVG, `test_drawio.svg`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" width="373px" height="223px" viewBox="-0.5 -0.5 373 223" style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);"><defs/><g><path d="M 141 71 L 186 71 L 186 151 L 220.9 151" fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="3" stroke-miterlimit="10" pointer-events="stroke"/><path d="M 227.65 151 L 218.65 155.5 L 220.9 151 L 218.65 146.5 Z" fill="#000000" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="3" stroke-miterlimit="10" pointer-events="all"/><rect x="1" y="1" width="140" height="140" fill="#ffffff" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="3" pointer-events="all"/><g transform="translate(-0.5 -0.5)"><switch><foreignObject style="overflow: visible; text-align: left;" pointer-events="none" width="100%" height="100%" requiredFeatures="http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/feature#Extensibility"><div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" style="display: flex; align-items: unsafe center; justify-content: unsafe center; width: 138px; height: 1px; padding-top: 71px; margin-left: 2px;"><div style="box-sizing: border-box; font-size: 0; text-align: center; "><div style="display: inline-block; font-size: 17px; font-family: Helvetica; color: #000000; line-height: 1.2; pointer-events: all; white-space: normal; word-wrap: normal; ">Some text<br style="font-size: 17px" />that usually<br style="font-size: 17px" />breaks when <br style="font-size: 17px" />exported to SVG</div></div></div></foreignObject><text x="71" y="76" fill="#000000" font-family="Helvetica" font-size="17px" text-anchor="middle">Some text...</text></switch></g><ellipse cx="301" cy="151" rx="70" ry="70" fill="#ffffff" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="3" pointer-events="all"/><g transform="translate(-0.5 -0.5)"><switch><foreignObject style="overflow: visible; text-align: left;" pointer-events="none" width="100%" height="100%" requiredFeatures="http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/feature#Extensibility"><div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" style="display: flex; align-items: unsafe center; justify-content: unsafe center; width: 138px; height: 1px; padding-top: 151px; margin-left: 232px;"><div style="box-sizing: border-box; font-size: 0; text-align: center; "><div style="display: inline-block; font-size: 17px; font-family: Helvetica; color: #000000; line-height: 1.2; pointer-events: all; white-space: normal; word-wrap: normal; ">Some more<br />text<br />that usually<br />breaks in<br />SVG</div></div></div></foreignObject><text x="301" y="156" fill="#000000" font-family="Helvetica" font-size="17px" text-anchor="middle">Some more...</text></switch></g></g><switch><g requiredFeatures="http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/feature#Extensibility"/><a transform="translate(0,-5)" xlink:href="https://www.diagrams.net/doc/faq/svg-export-text-problems" target="_blank"><text text-anchor="middle" font-size="10px" x="50%" y="100%">Viewer does not support full SVG 1.1</text></a></switch></svg>
```

So, I try this command first:

```
$ wkhtmltopdf.exe test_drawio.svg test_drawio.pdf
Loading page (1/2)
Printing pages (2/2)
Done
```

This results with PDF:

[image: pdfout1]

So, the resulting PDF is like A4, which is not what I want - I want a PDF of the same size as the SVG.

SVG has `width="373px" height="223px"`; so assuming dots-per-inch (ie. pixels-per-inch) of 96, I have for size in inches:

- width: 373/96 = 3.88542 in
- height: 223/96 = 2.32292 in

... and I try this command:

```
$ wkhtmltopdf.exe --dpi 96 --page-width 3.88542in --page-height 2.32292in test_drawio.svg test_drawio.pdf
Loading page (1/2)
Printing pages (2/2)
Done
```

This results with PDF:

[image: pdfout2]

Better, but there are some margins, which I'd like to get rid of (if I open the SVG in Inkscape, it shows a "tight box" with no margin - unfortunately Inkscape v1.0.2-2 cannot handle the texts in this SVG).

So, I try to manually set the margins:

```
$ wkhtmltopdf.exe --dpi 96 -L 0in -R 0in -T 0in -B 0in --page-width 3.88542in --page-height 2.32292in test_drawio.svg test_drawio.pdf
Loading page (1/2)
Printing pages (2/2)
Done
```

... which results with PDF:

[image: pdfout3]

... and there are *still* margins at right and at bottom.

Is it possible to use wkhtmltopdf to export SVG to PDF, exactly as the specified size in SVG - without additions of any margins/whitespace?

Comment: seemingly, (found this by trial and error), if I multiply the pixel sizes with 0.805, and then use `--page-width 300px --page-height 179px`, then it is clipped right - but I don't see where might this factor come from.

Comment: Try dpi 120 ... 96/120 = 0.8 which is close to your factor. 120dpi is common resolution for PDF

Comment: Thanks @KevinBrown - turns out, just 0.805 doesn't quite work; apparently those extra margins are dependent somehow on the input file aspect ratio as well? Also, it seems when forcing `--page-width` and `--page-height`, `--dpi` is ignored ... EDIT: also posted [Incorrect layout when explicitly setting PDF page size for standalone SVG in wkhtmltopdf 0.13 · Issue #4992 · wkhtmltopdf/wkhtmltopdf](https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/wkhtmltopdf/issues/4992)